# Instantiate Python subclasses from different directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, subclass

I have some modules that are in different directories. How can I instantiate classes in these `module`s only if the classes are subclasses of `ParentClass`? Essentially, I am trying something like this below and want to know how I can implement `child_class_name`

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
from parent_class import ParentClass

instances = []

script_path1 = r'/some/different/directory/some_child.py'
script_path2 = r'/some/different/directory/another_child.py'

for script_path in [script_path1, script_path2]:

    module = SourceFileLoader('module', script_path).load_module()

    child_class_name = "If a class in this module is a subclass of ParentClass"

    ChildClass = getattr(module, child_class_name)
    instances.append(ChildClass())
```

Comment: i didn't understand what you need exactly, how to check if `ChildClass` is a subclass ? or loop through all class objects in the module to find which one is a subclass ?

Comment: The latter, loop through all class objects in the module to find which one is a subclass so that I can create `ChildClass` Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with this comprehension list:

```
childclasses = [obj for obj in vars(module).values() 
                   if isinstance(obj,type) and issubclass(obj,ParentClass)]
```

`vars(module).values()` returns all objects living in the module.

Then you can filter the subclasses with `issubclass(obj,ParentClass)`.

(`isinstance` will just help to filter class objects.)

---

`childclasses` is a list of classes that you can instantiate directly, without using `getattr` :

```
for ChildClass in childclasses:
    instances.append(ChildClass())
```

---

**EDIT** :

To avoid `ParentClass` you can convert the list to a set, and remove it if it exists :

```
childclasses = set([obj for obj in vars(module).values() 
                       if isinstance(obj,type) and issubclass(obj,ParentClass)])
if ParentClass in childclasses:
    childclasses.remove(ParentClass)
```

or add another test in the comprehension :

```
childclasses = [obj for obj in vars(module).values() 
                       if isinstance(obj,type) and
                       issubclass(obj,ParentClass)and 
                       obj is not ParentClass ]
```

Comment: This is a beautiful solution! Just one question, how can I remove `ParentClass` from `childclasses`, which looks like `[<class 'module.SomeChild'>, <class 'parent_class.ParentClass'>]`? I think this is because in each child module there is `from parent_class import ParentClass` at the top.